# Yii Session Not Working

Tags: php, session, yii, webserver, session-variables

Some problem is coming when I am uploading site to online server. User authentication was working on my local computer but when I am trying to upload it to a server, it is not working. When I sign in, it redirects me back to the login page.

I have checked out and come to the point that when the page refreshes, the user info from session flush away and it redirects back to login page.

```
$this->setState('username', $user->username);
```

setState method is also not giving information on next page.

Please help me out with possible solution.

Thanks

Comment: can you try CarDumper::dump($_SESSION) to confirm that the session is actually getting flused?

Comment: Compare servers and local phpinfo(), there will be some differences regarding session handling.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you session was started automatically in php.ini config "session.auto_start = 1" or it was started manually by session_start() or Yii similar function

```
$session=new CHttpSession;
  $session->open();
```

And check your session status by session_status() function.